# How to know which method performed selector in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, oop, selector

I have really simple example, but I can't understand how I could get information about the method that call selector inside it. For example:

```
-(void)methodOne {
   [self performSelector:@selector(methodTwo:)];
}
-(void)methodTwo:(id)sender {
   //How to know which method performed selector???
}
```

I think this example is pretty simple, I just need to understand this, again, the question is, how could I know from **methodTwo:** which method perform selector, so from which method I called **methodTwo:**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do want to know which method calls your `methodTwo`, you can look at call stack. Look at this ...

```
-(void)methodOne {
  [self performSelector:@selector(methodTwo:)];
}

-(void)methodTwo:(id)sender {
  NSLog( @"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols][1]);
  NSLog( @"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols][2]);
}
```

... and the log output (simplified) is ...

```
0x014ef671 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
0x00002307 -[CMAppDelegate methodOne] + 55
```

... `callStackSymbols` returns `NSArray` with call stack symbols, so, you can look at index 1 to get method which did you call your method. As you can see, there's `NSObject`'s `performSelector` and it's because you called `methodTwo` via `performSelector`. If you change your `methodOne` in this way ...

```
-(void)methodOne {
  [self methodTwo:nil];
}
```

... the output is ...

```
0x000022fe -[CMAppDelegate methodOne] + 62
0x000025d6 -[CMAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 374
```

... that's it. Your question is answered, but I dunno why do you want this. You probably don't want to know which method exactly did call your method, but which object initiated this call chain. An example is button - you can have one method to handle more buttons and there's `sender` argument to distinguish between these buttons as @stavash pointed out.

Comment: Seems you mentioned the call stack method of `NSThread` before me while I was still typing! :-p

Answer (score 2):

Try using performSelector:withObject:

```
-(void)methodOne {
   NSString *identifierStr = @"methodOne";
   [self performSelector:@selector(methodTwo:) withObject:identifierStr];
}
-(void)methodTwo:(NSString *)senderIdentifierStr {
   NSLog(@"Sent by %@",senderIdentifierStr);
}
```

Comment: There's a `performSelector:withObject:` that you can use. The `...afterDelay:0.0` bit is redundant.

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the NSObject documentation and it has only the "afterDelay:" version, though the NSObject Protocol documentation also has the shortened version. Weird, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, it's in documentation. You're mixing two things - NSObject class and NSObject protocol. Both do exist.

Comment: I know they both exist, it's just that the documentation for the "performSelector:withObject:" isn't in the NSObject documentation.http://i923.photobucket.com/albums/ad76/stavash/1.png

Comment: Read it again, yes, it's there. I. Conforms to NSObject protocol, first clue. II. There's section Adopted Protocols and this method is listed there. All these things ARE in NSObject class documentation.

Comment: Robert, I understand it's there but it's not in the STANDARD NSObject document, you need to dig to find it. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can't know from the second method which method called it, at least not without going through the call stack (see `NSThread`) but you can pass this information from the first method like this:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    [self doSomethingElseWithCallee: NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) andSender: self];
}

- (void)doSomethingElseWithCallee: (NSString *)selector andSender: (id)sender] {
    // Do something…
}
```

Or you could just pass the selector (of type `SEL`) right away, instead of a string:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    [self doSomethingElseWithCallee: _cmd andSender: self];
}

- (void)doSomethingElseWithCallee: (SEL)selector andSender: (id)sender] {
    // Do something…
}
```

By the way, `_cmd` is a special argument that the Objective-C runtime passes to your method, along with `self` (the current object). They're not included in your method signature, but the compiler does all the work for you. ;-)

All hail the Objective-C language! :-p